# AWS CDK cannot find my credentials at all

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am following the tutorial linked here using Python on Windows: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html

Everything seems fine until I try to use `cdk deploy`, and end up getting the following error:

```
Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment
```

I have tried configuring the credentials through both AWS CLI and environment variables. Using the `-v` flag, it does not seem to find my credentials at all, even though AWS CLI seems to detect that the credentials work.

These are what my credential files look like:

credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = *****************
aws_secret_access_key = **************
aws_session_token= ****************
```

config:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html#cli-environment, possibly delete the env variables and make sure that the config files are in right directory

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, can you please confirm that the aws-cli works properly with your credentials? For example, what do get if you type: `aws sts get-caller-identity`?

Comment: Also, I see that you have a session token... Most likely, you are executing under an assumed role... What's the use case here? Session-based credentials are temporary and therefore, hardcoding them in your AWS credentials file is generally not the way to go...